# C++ unique_ptr versus friend class private destructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, destructor, friend, unique-ptr

I have this arrangement:

```
class LexedFile
    {
    friend class Lex;
//...
private:
    ~LexedFile();
    };

class Lex
    {
//...
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<LexedFile> > Files;
    };
```

A Lex is the sole creator of `LexedFile` objects and retains ownership of all the `LexedFile` objects it creates in a map. Unfortunately, the compiler complains mightily about this due to visibility rules from the map variable to the `LexedFile` destructor. I can fix that problem by making `~LexedFile()` public, but of course the reason I made it private is to reinforce the decision that objects of that type belong only to `Lex` objects.

My question is: what are my portable options for making `unique_ptr` happy and still keeping `~LexedFile()` private? By portable, I guess it has to at least work with the latest g++ and the latest Visual C++.

I took a stab at inserting something like:

```
friend class std::unique_ptr<LexedFile>;
```

but even if it had worked (it didn't) it kinda seemed like relying on assumptions about the implementation that might not be portable.

Comment: pass your own deleter instead of using the default one :)

Comment: `friend class std::default_delete<LexedFile>` could also possibly work, depending on the implementation, but I wouldn't count on it and it also probably exposes your destructor more than you would like it to be exposed

Comment: Or even better `friend std::unique_ptr<LexedFile>::deleter_type;` which would also work for a `std::unique_ptr` that uses a custom deleter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just instantiate `std::unique_ptr` with your own deleter. I think this will work:

```
class LexedFile
{
    friend class Lex;

//...
private:
    struct Deleter
    {
        void operator()(LexedFile *file) const
        {
            delete file;
        }
    };

    ~LexedFile();
};

class Lex
{
//...
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<LexedFile, LexedFile::Deleter>> Files;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! After waiting for a download of the (nearly) standard and poking around, I decided to go with your friend declaration. It seemed like it ought to be portable (after changing the "class" to "struct"), and the alternative of making a wrapper just to fight permissions was depressing. :-) Whatever holes it might have, it definitely still outlaws anybody directly calling delete on that class, which is the main reminder I wanted to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @RonBurk I'm almost positive that you're relying on undefined behavior, by the way, as long as you're ok with that.

Comment: How so? 20.7.1 seems to require unique_ptr to use default_delete. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that default_delete calls delete directly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195840/friending-classes-defined-in-the-std-namespace-any-guarantees

Comment: 20.7.1.1.2 says of operator()(T* ptr): "Effect: calls delete on ptr." Still not seeing what's making you doubt.

Comment: yes, lots of functions have effects but the standard doesn't specify that those effects are carried out by the functions themselves or that friendship has any effect of them

Comment: lots of effects in the library are carried out by helper classes and such, and friendship doesn't apply transitively to called functions