# Friending classes defined in the std namespace: any guarantees?

Tags: c++, std, language-lawyer

This question came up as I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193108/c-unique-ptr-versus-friend-class-private-destructor/15193179): does the standard allow and make any guarantees about `friend`-ing standard library classes and/or functions?

In this particular case, the situation the question was whether:

```
class MyUserDefinedType
{
    friend struct std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>;

private:
    ~MyUserDefinedType() { }
}
```

is guaranteed to allow `MyUserDefinedType` to be stored in a `std::unique_ptr<MyUserDefinedType>` or `std::shared_ptr<MyUserDefinedType>` object with the default deleter.

In general, are classes described in the standard library required to implement their functionality directly, or can they use any arbitrary level of indirection? For example, is it possible that

- `std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>` is actually a `using` alias of a class defined in an inner namespace of `std`, in which case the `friend` declaration would be illegal

or

- `std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>` calls some other class that actually does the deleting, in which case the `friend` declaration would not have the desired effect

or something else along those lines?

My guess is that this is <s>UB</s> not guaranteed to work but I am curious if this is addressed specifically by the standard.

This specific example given above works for clang trunk (w/libc++) and GCC 4.7.2 (w/libstdc++), FWIW

Comment: I don't know the answer, but "befriending" `std::default_delete<>` will, if it works, enable nearly anyone to call the destructor of the class. It makes me wonder why make the destructor private in the first place if then a friend declaration is used that makes it (nearly) public again. (Admittedly, it would still mean that objects of automatic storage couldn't be de-allocated.)

Comment: I would not have expected that to be true (though I stopped being a C++ expert a decade ago); experimentally it seems not to be true for latest g++ and vc++, FWIW.

Comment: i didn't think the solution was a good one, i suggested implementing a new deleter

Comment: It _might_ make sense with a PIMPL, @jogojapan, since the class would only be visible to code that expects its members to be accessible.  If, e.g., he had `MyUserDefinedTypeImpl` as the implementation for `MyUserDefinedType`, then allowing `MyUserDefinedTypeImpl` to befriend both `MyUserDefinedType` and `std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedTypeImpl>` might make sense in theory, to provide both the protections of private inheritance and the cleanliness of a public destructor.  Still not ideal, for sure, but there is at least one theoretical use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible that `std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>` is actually a using alias of a class defined in an inner namespace of std, in which case the friend declaration would be illegal?

**No**. Per Paragraph 20.7.1.1.2 of the C++11 Standard:

```
namespace std {
    template <class T> struct default_delete {
        constexpr default_delete() noexcept = default;
        template <class U> default_delete(const default_delete<U>&) noexcept;
        void operator()(T*) const;
    };
}
```

The fact that it has to be a class template is explicitly specified. This means it cannot be an alias template. If that was the case, it would also be impossible to specialize it.

> is it possible that `std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>` calls some other class that actually does the deleting, in which case the friend declaration would not have the desired effect?

**Yes.** Nothing in the Standard specifies that the call cannot be done by some internal helper. Per Paragraph 20.1.1.2:

```
void operator()(T *ptr) const;
```

> 3 Effects: calls `delete` on `ptr`.
>
> 4 Remarks: If `T` is an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed.

This only specifies what the *effect* of invoking the call operator on the `default_delete<>` functor should be, not *how* this shall be achieved concretely (whether directly inside the body of the call operator, or by delegating the task to some member function of some other class).

Comment: your answer for the second part makes sense to me, but do you know if this issue is specifically addressed anywhere? is it explicitly UB to friend a standard class or just implicitly?

Comment: @StephenLin: Why should it be UB? It's just not a portable solution I believe, because the call to `delete` *could*, but does not have to, be performed by the `default_delete` class itself.

Comment: well, ok, i mean, it's behavior that changes the semantics of the program (such that it may or may not compile) and it's not defined...maybe UB is too strong but what else would it be? unspecified?

Comment: @StephenLin: It would just be non-portable code that behaves differently with different implementations. If your program has UB, an implementation is actually free to do *anything* when your program is executed. This is not the case here.

Comment: ok, that's fair, i meant undefined behavior as simply "behavior that is not defined"

Comment: @StephenLin: Ok, then I think "unspecified behavior" might be a better expression.

Comment: but this is about on par with overloading function templates in `std`, right? it's basically something that will pretty much work in any implementation in practice but isn't guaranteed to? shouldn't it be addressed to prevent people from relying on this kind of thing?

Comment: @StephenLin: No, I don't think so. The Standard explicitly forbids introducing new overloads in the `std` namespace. You can *specialize* some (not all) of the templates defined in the `std` namespace.

Comment: but maybe it should also explicitly forbid `friend`-ing `std` functions and classes, if the behavior cannot be relied upon to do anything.

Comment: @StephenLin: I would say it's not in the philosophy of C++ to forbid any possible attempt to write non-portable code. But I'm thinking about  the meaning of "Equivalent to" above

Comment: OK, well thanks for the input and confirming (I think) that this cannot be relied upon

Comment: @StephenLin: Yes, I do believe this cannot be relied upon

Comment: Actually, the phrase _equivalent to_ isn't used in the _Effects:_ section. It just says _calls `delete` on `ptr`_. Not sure if that changes anything, though.

Comment: well, regardless of this specific case, what about in general? can you friend containers, allocators, etc, so they can accesss your private constructors?

Comment: @jogojapan: Hm, you're right, I assumed specifying something in the "Effects" section actually *meant* to specify it to be "Equivalent to", but that's likely not the case. Let me re-think

Comment: @StephenLin: You can, and if it compiles with your implementation of the C++ standard library and you are not interested in writing portable code, you are OK. Your program does not have UB. I think you should just not expect that to work with all implementations.

Comment: @AndyProwl ok, I guess that makes sense...I obviously don't think its a good idea to do this and think it would be better if it were addressed explicitly as disallowed, but I realize they can't plug all these holes

Comment: @AndyProwl: your second point perfectly nails down the issue of `friend`: the lack of transitivity. In a way it helps narrowing down the consequences of a class private interface change, but the inability to delegate part of the work is extremely annoying and really hampers composability and modularity :(

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Agreed. Although having transitivity by default may be undesired as well (what if I want to trust only one class, but not the classes that are trusted by that class?). Maybe having a possibility to specify both semantics (transitive and non-transitive friendship) would be a good thing.

Comment: @AndyProwl so how sure are you about "Effects" and "Equivalent to" for `std::default_delete`?

Comment: @StephenLin: That was a misunderstanding of mine. It doesn't really apply here, as @jogojapan correctly observed. I still believe that the statement in "Effects" means "ends up calling `delete` on `ptr`", but does not say where from.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, are classes described in the standard library required to implement their functionality directly, or can they use any arbitrary level of indirection?

In *general* an implementation may indirect as much as it wants. Have e.g. a look at the implementations of standard containers and their iterators - or just use them wrong and see which templates are involved from the error messages. However, since `default_delete` is nothing magic, that should be a one-liner, you can expect it to do the work itself, but it's not guaranteed.

> My guess is that this is UB but I am curious if this is addressed specifically by the standard.

It's not UB, it's just unspecified.

You could be sure if you just specialized `default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>` (it *is* allowed to specialize standard libraray templates), but I would not do that.

I would not use friendship at all, especially not if it comes to templates that have not been specialized. Consider this:

```
//your code
class MyUserDefinedType
{
    friend struct std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>; //for deletion
private:  
    int veryPrivateData;
    ~MyUserDefinedType() { }
};

//evil colleague's code:
namespace std {
  //we may specialize std-templates for UDTs...
  template<>
  struct default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>
  {
    constexpr default_delete() noexcept = default;
    template <class U> default_delete(const default_delete<U>&) noexcept {}
    void operator()(T* pt) const { delete pt; }

    //sneaky...
    void access(MyUserDefinedType& mudt, int i) const
    { mudt.veryPrivateData = i; }
  };
}

void somewhere_deep_in_the_code()
{
  MyUserDefinedType& myUDT = /*something...*/;
  std::default_delete<MyUserDefinedType>().access(myUDT, 42); //tricked you!
}
```

Friends can do *anything* to you. Choose them with caution. In this case, I'd really recommend a custom deleter - assuming it makes any sense making the destructor private but providing access to it via the deleter.

Comment: yeah i suggested a custom deleter, this is not my recommended solution

Comment: +1 thanks for the input though, I'm still hoping someone can find a very authoritative quote about `friend`-ing standard classes/functions